# Cant connect to SQLSERVER using Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse

I am a student and I am working on the below code. I have been looking for a solution by my own but can't find any.

Here's the code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;


public class ConexionSQL {


        private static Connection cn;

        public static Connection getConnection() {
            try {

                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://Frankcpu:1433;database=Dentista;user=sa;password=123;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;loginTimeout=30;");

            }catch(Exception e) {
                cn= null;

            }
            return cn;
        }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection pruebaCn = ConexionSQL.getConnection();
    if(pruebaCn!=null) {
        System.out.println("Conectado");
        System.out.println(pruebaCn);
    }else {
        System.out.println("No Conectado");
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: The answer will come **a lot** more quickly if you tell us what errors you get, whether you checked the connection works with another program, etc., i.e. what you already did to try and diagnose the issue.

Comment: Also, don't catch `Exception` instead of a particular exception. What exception was it? What did it say?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: there are no errors, it just runs and I get  "not connected" in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of your code seems ok. Then you could try this :

```
String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\sqlexpress;user=sa;password=secret";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
```

Or you can also usae the Properties class:

```
String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\sqlexpress";
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("user", "sa");
properties.put("password", "secret");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, properties);
```

Check if your JDBC is properly connected to eclipse, and check if the classpath is correct, also.